# Quiero renombrar cada GCI por su fecha

Tags: r

En el siguiente código, renombro las imágenes por su fecha, pero me queda al final como

X20181223T140049_20181223T140048_T20HQK_2018_12_23

#Creamos una coleccion de imagenes

```
collection_imag<- ee$ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")$
  filterBounds(roi)$
  filter(ee$Filter$lt("CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT", 1))
```

#function to calculate satellite index

```
func_gci <-function(image){
  gci =image$expression(
    expression = 'NIR/GREEN-1',
    opt_map = list(
      'NIR' = image$select('B8'),
      'GREEN' = image$select('B3')
    )
  )
  return(image$addBands(gci$rename('GCI')))
}

collection_gci<- collection_imag$map(func_gci)$
  select("GCI")$map(function(image) {
    image$clip(roi)
  }
  )

rescale_rename <- function(image) {
  date <- ee$Date(image$get("system:time_start"))$format('YYYY_MM_dd')
  return(image$select('GCI')$rename(date))
}

gci_rescaled <- collection_gci$map(rescale_rename)
```

## Crear una grilla regular de 10 metros x 10 metros centrada en los polígonos

```
grid <- poligono%>%
  st_make_grid(what = "centers", cellsize = c(250, 250))%>%
  st_intersection(poligono)
```

## Extraer los valores de la imagen apilada utilizando la grilla

```
output <- double()
for (i in seq_along(grid)) {
  output <-ee_extract(gci_rescaled, sf_as_ee(grid), sf = F, scale = 10)
  }
```

Al final yo quiero un dataframe con todas los valores de GCI, donde cada columna sea una fecha y la primer columna las coordenadas.